# Ways to bump a warlock's attack roll?

Tags: dnd-4e, warlock

We've got a scourge warlock with the infernal pact that's having a rough time being able to hit things.  Right now her attack mod is 15 (we're level 13's).  I know that warlocks don't need to have as high a mod to hit because non-ac defense are usually lower, but she seems to be having a rough go at hitting anything.

What ways exist to amplify a warlock's attack mod?

Her attack roll stats:

- +5 con mod
- +4 enhancement wand
- +6 half level

She currently doesn't have implement expertise for her wand.

Comment: Could you give some examples, and perhaps statistics?

Comment: "She currently doesn't have implement expertise for her wand." - at paragon, this is +2 to hit, or stated differently, 10% more hits

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Feats, Items, special feat items, and initial character build.**

At level 13, she should have the following as a striker:

- Primary stat of (18 at level 1, +3 from levlling up) = +5
- Enhancement bonus of +3 from item
- +6 half level
- +2 wand/rod expertise
- +1 superior implement training (accurate or specialized implement)
- +2 combat advantage from hidden sniper + shadow walk

3 feats can add +5 to hit quite trivally.

This means, that (save if you're using old monsters from MM1 versus fort, you should be attacking versus level+12 or 25. The "average monster" attack at this level is Level+3, meaning there's a serious problem if you're under it.

Your base to-hit as given is 55%, which is completely average/adequate as attacks go for even level monsters. Depending on party composition this is unfortunate, and if you're attacking fort all the time, MM1 and 2 mobs have unusually high fortitudes. Personally, I've found myself being resentful of accuracy when it drops below 65-70%.

If you apply the bonuses above, that 55% turns into a 80%, which is far more acceptable.

For general advice, look [at the charop handbook](http://community.wizards.com/go/thread/view/75882/28769833/Walk_With_Me_in_Hell%3a_The_Warlocks_Guide). Without more specific build details, I cannot offer specific build advice (which is better done in chat).

Comment: Also, not as part of an answer, but general service, I seem to have helped quite a few people build characters more to requirements. Drop by my "office" (The Back Room) and I'll help optimize this one and link to that chat.